# To check when knockout binding is complete

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using knockout to bind the controls on my page and after the binding is complete I use window.print() to print the page. all these functions are called in

```
$(document).ready(function (){//}
```

So the flow is like this: the page loads and due to window.print(); it goes to the print wizard.
Now the problem is that the page goes to print wizard and the bindings are incomplete although i have used

```
ko.applyBindings(object to be bound);
```

before window.print();  Is there a method or way in knockout that i can check if all the bindings are complete or not because writing it in document.ready() is not helping.

Comment: From the code given here you don't actually apply your bindings to a given object, you just call the apply bindings function, is this the exact code you use in your javascript file?

Comment: edited the question. The bindings are working fine. I can say that because when i cancel the print wizard the page is already bind.. i think the binding is taking time and before it even completes the print function is called theDarse

Comment: Please provide more of the code, including the html and javascript view-model

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... applyBindings should be synchronous so it should be good to go after it's called.

Are you doing some AJAX call after this to actually load the data? If so, that's where you can add logic to maintain some kind of 'ready' boolean.

You could set a boolean to false, then immediately true after you call applyBindings, but I suspect there's something else going on if you're print screen is coming up empty.

Comment: ajax call to load the data is before the applyBindings and the print wizard doesnt come up with an empty page but an incompletly bound page. Weird stuff..

Comment: Is there any custom css for printing that might be hiding stuff?

Comment: Also... the AJAX call is async, so even if it's before the call to applyBindings, it may not be complete yet. Add a boolean that you set after the callback from the AJAX call is complete. Only show the priont button once that boolean becomes true.